# How to get line number values to the same row in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement that I need to give line number value to the row if same data is repeated

Input

```
create table test(id int,name varchar(10),sal int)
insert test values(101,'hdfc',15000)
insert test values(101,'hdfc',15000)
insert test values(101,'hdfc',15000)
select id+name+sal from test
```

Expected output:

```
lineno:1 101,hdfc,15000
lineno:2 101,hdfc,15000
lineno:3 101,hdfc,15000
```

If new record inserted then again it should start from `lineno1`
ex:

```
lineno:1 101,IDBI,15000
```

Note: lineno is hardcoded value but the numbers should increase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `CTE` and `Row_number()`: (Assuming you need results in a single column, otherwise please remove string concatenation within CTE)

```
;with cte as (
    select id, 
      convert(varchar(10), id) +', '+ name +', '+ convert(varchar(10), sal) cols,
      row_number() over(partition by id,name, sal order by id) rn
    from test
)
select 'lineno:' + convert(varchar(10), rn) + ' ' + cols as mystring
from cte
order by id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6b46/2)**

```
|                  MYSTRING |
-----------------------------
| lineno:1 101, hdfc, 15000 |
| lineno:2 101, hdfc, 15000 |
| lineno:3 101, hdfc, 15000 |
| lineno:1 101, IDBI, 15000 |
```